# How to reprint <dataTemplate> in xaml only after all binding are updated (windows phone 8.1)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list View that has a data template that that has textblocks with their text value is binding to data.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              Grid.Row="2" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,70"


              Foreground="Red" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >

            <DataTemplate>

                 <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_PlayerOneBid"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                                   Text="{Binding PlayerOneBid}" 
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   FontFamily="ArialBlack"
                                   Height="25"
                                   Width="23"
                                     TextAlignment="Center"
                                   />

                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_PlayerTwoBid"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"                                  
                                   Text="{Binding PlayerTwoBid}" 
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   FontFamily="ArialBlack"
                                   Height="25"
                                   Width="23"
                                     TextAlignment="Center"
                                   />

              </DataTemplate>


        </ListView.ItemTemplate>



    </ListView>
```

the problem im haveing here is that this data template is printing twice. with 4 textblocks instead of 2 . is there a way to restirct the template from printing until all values are set ?

code for setting values.

```
PlayerOneBid = 1 ;
PlayerTwoBid = 2 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Visibility Converter which will return `Collapsed` when the string is null or empty, and `Visible` otherwise.

```
    public sealed class EmptyToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;
    var str = value.ToString();
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Then on your page, declare the resource:

Then add use the converter on each `TextBlock`:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              Grid.Row="2" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,70"


              Foreground="Red" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >

            <DataTemplate>

                 <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_PlayerOneBid"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                                   Text="{Binding PlayerOneBid}" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding PlayerOneBid, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   FontFamily="ArialBlack"
                                   Height="25"
                                   Width="23"
                                     TextAlignment="Center"
                                   />

                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_PlayerTwoBid"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"                                  
                                   Text="{Binding PlayerTwoBid}" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding PlayerTwoBid, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   FontFamily="ArialBlack"
                                   Height="25"
                                   Width="23"
                                     TextAlignment="Center"
                                   />

              </DataTemplate>


        </ListView.ItemTemplate>



</ListView>
```